# Online app which generates beats sounds and allows user to download sound file

Tags: gratis, web-apps, audio

Looking for an online service or an app which allows user to combines sounds of two different frequencies and generates the sound. Also the user should have the option to download the generated sound file in wav format. I am looking for a service similar to [this](https://onlinetonegenerator.com/) but allows for adding more frequencies together.

Answer (score 2):

An app rather than an online service would be [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) which is free, Open Source and available for Windows, macOS, GNU/Linux and other operating systems.

The process is simple:

1. Create a new (mono) track: `Tracks->Add New->Mono`
2. Generate your 1st tone: `Generate->Tone` *select frequency & duration.*
3. Repeat for Second Tone
4. Mix the two: `Tracks->Mix->Mix & Render` *to new track*
5. Repeat as often as needed.
6. Export in desired format, `File->Export->`*Pick a format*
7. No need to download as already on local file system

Example:
[image: Example]

Of course you can do a lot more with Audacity than just generate beat notes.